# refresh a web page in my ruby controller function

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, refresh

I would like to update my web page from my ruby function: on the 'start' button in my web page (slim code) , i call a function (runexecution) in my controller: this function is an endless loop every minute and should update the content of my page (input , for example) from results generated by my runexecution function: how? a render ..another ideas ?

My config:
Linux debian 7
ruby 2.1
Rails 4.17
mysql 5

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want to do long/short polling and this is easier accomplished with javascript

```
HTML/JAVASCRIPT
<script type="text/javascript">
  setTimeout(function(){
  location.reload();
  },1000) // Refresh page every 1000 milliseconds = 1s
</script>

HAML
:javascript
  setTimeout(function(){
    location.reload();
  },60000) // 60000 = time in milliseconds


:javascript
  setTimeout(function(){
    // Make ajax request to run execution
    $.get('/runexecution', {}, function(result){
      // Do something with result.
    })
  },60000) // 60000 = time in milliseconds
```

Comment: yes it is a solution but the javascript code do not run my 'runexecution' function in my rails controller : javascript refresh my page in an endless loop with delay but do not execute my ruby fonction

Comment: You can always use the above code to execute your controller method via. For instance, assuming that you're in your local development environment. Just edited the above answer to give you an idea.